# Separate CSS files for Light and Dark Mode

Tags: html, css

I want my web app to have both light and dark modes and users should be able to switch back and forth anytime they like it.

Does this require two separate CSS files i.e. one for light and one for dark mode and setting the correct one using Javascript or can it be done with just one CSS file?

Comment: Anything you can do with multiple CSS files you can also do with one CSS file. It might be as simple as changing a class on the body element. That said, the CSS might be a bit simpler to write if separate files are used. Personally, I would prefer one file, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: There are options like `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {...}`, but I'm not sure how well supported they are.

Comment: Here's a really handy guide: https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/

Comment: Good support for the media query these days: https://caniuse.com/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: I guess another advantage of using separate files is that we can use the same class names, correct? This way instead of updating class names for different elements, we can simply point to appropriate css file. Having said that I also like the idea of using a single CSS file. Just trying to find the right balance. BTW, the link to the guide is very useful. Thank you!

Comment: "can use the same class names". Well, you still can with a single file. No need to change them. You could put all the dark ones inside an @media rule, for example, and just set different styles for each class. Or you could use JS to toggle a class on the body element and target elements in the style sheet separately with something like `.dark .wrapper` and `.light .wrapper` etc.

Comment: @ralph.m Makes perfect sense! Thank you for detailed explanations and the links. I really appreciate it.